# Android service, that will access a remote desktop PC

Tags: android, remote-access, remote-desktop

I would just like to know if it is possible or not. If it is possible can you please point me where to start?

The idea:
I would like to make a service that will run when my tablet boots up. This service will automatically run a remote desktop access app (from google play market) and it will establish a connection with predefined settings, so I do not have to manually start the remote desktop app and click "Connect". Is this possible even if I do not have the source code of the remote desktop app? Can you please help me?

Or is there another way to establish remote desktop connection from my Android tablet right when the tablet boots up?

PS: I am not doing this for somebody else, it is just for my needs, so please dont look at this as it is nonsense because no one will run any app like this on startup anyways. :)

Thank you

Comment: This really depends on if the un-named app in question supports having details passed to it in a launch intent.  You'd probably have to ask its developer.  Of course you could make your own app - something that would be much more on topic here.